# route.snapshot giving null in angular8 resolver

Tags: angular

I am using resolver in Angular8 app.

```
  resolve() {
    let id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    console.log(id)
    return this.http.get<User>(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/`)
  }
```

In this code I am getting **null** in log. But in the component itself i am getting the correct **id**

Please help

Comment: Have a look at the example in https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-pre-fetching-component-data; give a [mcve] if you still can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

let's try with below code

I have same problem but got the solution.

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
        let id;
        if (!!route.queryParams && !!route.queryParams.id) {
            id = Number(route.queryParams.id);
        }
        if (!!route.paramMap.get('id')) {
            id = route.paramMap.get('id');
        }
    console.log(id)
    return this.http.get<User>(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/`)
    }
```

hope above code will help you can debug the code and remove/avoid one if condition from their.

let me know if you still not get id in log.

thanks